# FB.Event.subscribe not working for auth.login, auth.logout and auth.statusChange

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins

facebook is allowing me to login with a pop up window, which is fine.

But I am not able to catch any event using FB.Event.subscribe.
i tried subscribing for auth.statusChange as many forum mentioned that. nothing seems to be working.

Even, this too is not working. What's wrong ?

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the problem.
In facebook app setting, my app domain was setup as localhost (it does not accept 127.0.0.1) and I was accessing my localhost as 127.0.0.1 and that created the problem.

When I started accessing the site as localhost, I was able to catch all the events.
Note this point.