# FB.Event.subscribe & FB.getLoginStatus not firing

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've looked through various documentations and questions here on stackoverflow and still can't figure out why the following code will not fire any of the FB.Event.subscribe events getLoginStatus.

```
<div id="fb-root">
<script>
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '{appID}', // App ID
            channelUrl: '{channelURL}', // Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
            oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

</script>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's appearing in your console? Are you getting in cross-site origin errors?

Comment: @Callum McLean There is nothing appearing in the console.  At one point I had a parenthesis in the wrong place and I was getting an  FB.init error but once I got that sorted out I haven't gotten anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else needs it I found the answer to my question on this other question:

[FB.Event.subscribe not working for auth.login, auth.logout and auth.statusChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727076/fb-event-subscribe-not-working-for-auth-login-auth-logout-and-auth-statuschange)

I went into facebook and updated the Canvas URL to my localhost URL and it worked.